# XCode Project Details?

Tags: xcode, project-management, projects

At the top of all the files in a project, it has that comment block with the programmer information and whatnot.

How do you change that? I remember setting it once. Somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
defaults write com.apple.xcode 'PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions' "{ORGANIZATIONNAME = 'your Company Name' ; }"
```

Here's the full list of options: [Xcode User Defaults.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/100-Xcode_User_Defaults/UserDefaultRef.html)

Answer (score 2):

Templates are stored at `/Developer/Library/Xcode/File Templates`. You can edit those to change the header.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to change the dynamic parts of that. Where do I go to change FULLUSERNAME and ORGINIZATIONDATE?

Comment: I have no idea what ORGINIZATIONDATE is, I meant ORGANIZATION. Monday.